# Difference between "Past Tense " and "Present Tense"

Tags: difference, tense, infinitive-vs-gerund

He began to move to leave the bus.

He begins moving to leave the bus.

I am on the bus now I try  to make a sentence to describe someone want to leave the bus.

SO, Should I use present or past? Infinitive or Gerund? Please help.

Comment: Is "he wants to leave the bus" happening as you're saying this sentence?

Comment: Yes, he wants to leave the bus, happening as I am saying this.

Comment: I see him leaving and  I want to express this.

Comment: If you see him leaving as you speak, that's just the present. If you saw him leave in the past, use past tense. Is there something else you're unclear about?

Comment: So. What is the past and what is present for the sentence. And what is suitable to use infinitive with to or Gerund.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please take the [tour] and read the [help] pages if you haven't already done so.

Comment: "He wants to leave the bus." is present. It's happening now.
"He wanted to leave the bus." is past. It happened it the past.

Answer (score 1):

I think a more natural way of conveying that idea would be:

He's getting ready to get off the bus.

Or

He's getting up from his seat to leave/get off the bus.

Answer (score 0):

The sense that you want to convey is not completely clear.

Is the person trying to leave the bus and having difficulty, or has the person just begun leaving the bus?

First, "move" is unnecessary because one cannot leave a bus by not moving. So you can say

> He is starting to leave the bus

or

> He has started leaving the bus

If you insist "move" in the sentence, you can say

He is starting to move in order to leave the bus

Answer (score 0):

> He begins to move...

But this is not natural or normal.

When you are on a bus. Do you say:

> A man comes in.  The man sits down.  The child looks out the window. The woman puts on make up. The child picks her nose ...

*Nobody gives a commentary about what is happening as it happens!*

Now you might be on a bus and there is a man who wants to get off the bus, You want to help the man and so you tell the driver:

> This man wants to leave the bus.

This is a present tense sentence using the "want to +infinitive" structure.

So think: *Why* are you speaking. *Who* are you talking to? *What* do you want to communicate?   And this should help you decide *How* to express yourself in English.